# Does the .failed() function need to be always put in an if statement? arduino-firebase library

Tags: firebase, arduino, nodemcu, arduino-c++

I have a code for Arduino sending data to Firebase as such:

```
void loop() {
  Firebase.setFloat("number", 42.0);

  if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.print("setting /number failed:");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());  
      return;
  }

  delay(1000);
  Firebase.setFloat("number", 43.0);

}
```

I've read the documentation of the library that is being used (arduino-firebase) and it said:

> **bool** failed()
>
> return: Whether the last command failed.

There is 2 question I wanna ask:

1. Does the *Firebase.failed()* need to be always put inside an *if statement* for the function to be useful?
2. What does the *return* statement do inside the *if statement*?

Any helpful respond would be appreciated!

Comment: `return;` as final statement is useless. Here it would allow to have additional code in case of success.

Comment: @Jarod42 I have edited the code in my question, now I have some code after the *if statement*. Does the return is being used to get out of the *if statement?*

Comment: To get out of the function. End of (block) statement to "exit" normally of the `if` statement.

Comment: @Jarod42 Do you mean by "function" is *Firebase.failed()* ?

Comment: I mean `return` exits from `void loop()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 As I know, there's 2 main void function that needs to be filled. It is `void setup()` & `void loop()`. If the code exits from `void loop()` what will it do? Jump to the very first code above `void setup()`?

Comment: It will do the same thing as when it reach the last instruction of the function.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the `Firebase.failed()` need to be always put inside an `if` statement for the function to be useful?

You might print its value...
but its main usage would be in `if`-statement (or equivalent).

> What does the return statement do inside the if statement?

[`return`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) exits/terminates the current function.

Below code:

```
void loop() {
  Firebase.setFloat("number", 42.0);

  if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.print("setting /number failed:");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());  
      return;
  }

  delay(1000);
  Firebase.setFloat("number", 43.0);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void loop() {
  Firebase.setFloat("number", 42.0);

  if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.print("setting /number failed: ");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());  
  } else {
      delay(1000);
      Firebase.setFloat("number", 43.0);
  }
}
```